# Vue3 - elements look like out of html, white space which can't remove

Tags: html, css, vuejs3, vue-router, whitespace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQlHo.png)I am learning VUE framework. I've created view routes and components like nav and footer in 'components' folder. I've tried to inject them to app.vue with and without parent div.pageContent with no result. **The problem I can't find source of is white space.** First I used BULMA to style and thought it causes issues - but not, with bootstrap is the same problem.

I also imported css reset to main.js following developer.mozilla.org but still no result.

My aim is to inject views pages between navigation and footer - is it even possible like this?

`app.vue:`

`

```
<script setup>
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import navComponents from './components/navComponents.vue'
import footerComponent from './components/footerComponent.vue'
</script>
<template>
    <div class="pageContent">
        <navComponents />
        <RouterView/>
        <footerComponent />
    </div>
</template>
```

`

my code on repo https://github.com/ChevyFanka/Arthem

i tried to reset css, change hierachy of vue components, different stylings, no result

giving a bottom 0 and position absolute to footer doesn't work

tried to look in:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/css-reset/#reset-features
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Vue_styling
https://copyprogramming.com/howto/vue-js-show-white-space-line-breaks

Comment: The content is taking up as much height as needed, which is not a lot, so it naturally creates a lot of white space.  Given a full page worth of content it will not show white space.  Your `/discography` page seems to show this the best.  The only issue seems to be the footer not always at the bottom of the page, but if I add `position: absolute` (which bottom: 0 requires) to your footer it [works fine](https://i.imgur.com/baJRCOi.png).  I'm not sure what the concern is over injecting view pages.  the routing and changing of page views seem to be fine.

Comment: thanks for reply. I also tried to give footer a pos.absolute and bottom 0. 
Now I have duplicated content of homePage, give footer absolute and bottom 0 and it is horrrible. content is behind footer and goes down and footer is not on the bottom.

Comment: It's just an issue of CSS.  Find the style that works for your app.  From the sound of it `position: fixed` may be better for your footer.  Will probably also require your page content be given padding to not overlap the footer.

Comment: looks like there was issue with VSC that's why I didn't see changes with p.absolute and bottom 0. Thanks for reply